# How did Euler solve the 4-whole-numbers-adding-up-to-a-perfect-square problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

So I was watching a video on Leonhard Euler about how he amazingly solved so many difficult problems and one of the many problems that he solved was this:

`Find four whole numbers, the sum of any two of which add up to a perfect square.`

The numbers he found were:
$$18530,~~~ 38114,~~~ 45986,~~~ 65570$$

I've searched everywhere on the net but I can't find how he solved this. 
Does anyone here know how he did it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the first thing to try is to find three whole numbers, the sum of any two of which add up to a perfect square.  See if you can find any pattern to the set of such triples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See page 129 and next of Yiu's book [The Elementary Mathematical Works of 
Leonhard Euler (1707 – 1783)](http://images.tamvy.multiply.multiplycontent.com/attachment/0/SBNVsAoKCrIAAB4eEEg1/Eulernotes.pdf?key=tamvy%3ajournal:35&nmid=93096378) (Dunham's comment appears [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=uKOVNvGOkhQC&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Concerning the referenced Euler paper "Recherches sur le problème de trois nombres carrés tels que la somme de deux quelconques moins le troisième fasse un nombre carré" you may find the french, english and a synopsis [here](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/pages/E796.html) (from the excellent ['The works of Leonhard Euler online'](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/)).